# Break core execution when external device modifies an address

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

At t32, we are able to break execution when code accesses a particular address/address range.
Is it possible to cause t32 to break execution when an external device modifies the value of a particular address (address not written to by the code, but from an external source like a HW)?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases there is no on-chip debug logic available to trigger on events of peripheral modules, but some exceptions exist. I'd recommend to contact Lauterbach Support (https://support.lauterbach.com), with details about the used processor and which event you would like to trigger on.

A more generic, but slower method exists if the processor supports *run-time memory access*. In this case you can use the `SNOOPer` feature to have the debugger poll the peripheral register and halt execution is a certain value is written. There is some delay between the event and halting the core, depending on how fast the debugger can poll the peripheral register.

Comment: is it possible to also redirect the values from the snooper window to a csv file?